# How do I set my elm package as deprecated?

Tags: package, elm

I would like to know, if there is anyway to mark my elm package as ***deprecated***. I did some search on elm discourse and there was a solution proposed to package deprecations using `@deprecated` flag.

Is that proposed solution implemented? Is there any new way to do that?

Comment: What does this have to do with Haskell?

Comment: @Noughtmare Sorry for the wrong tag. Since elm is based on haskell, therefore I thought there might be some haskell programmers who know elm as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way as such. You can add a warning to your docs, and note that Elm's semver will ensure that your package does not get offered to anyone once it falls behind what people are using.

Here is the top of one of my packages - you could add something on line 2 of the comment for example

[image]

Comment: You mean the package's docs? How can I do that?